# javascript onclick for more Info

Tags: javascript, onclick, appendchild

I'm trying to make a list. When i click each item on the list, description will be displayed. Right now my code only displays the items, and when i click an item, descriptions of All of the items are shown. Can anyone help me fix this problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function moreInfo(){
var para= document.createElement("p")
var divObj = document.getElementById("p1");
divObj.appendChild(para);
var divObj = document.getElementById("p2");
divObj.appendChild(para);
var divObj = document.getElementById("p3");
divObj.appendChild(para);
var divObj = document.getElementById("p4");
divObj.appendChild(para);
var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is good");
para.appendChild(txt);
var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is bad");
para.appendChild(txt);
var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is pretty");
para.appendChild(txt);
var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is ugly");
para.appendChild(txt);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="p1" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo()"> 
    Good
   </p>
<div id="p2" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo()"> 
    Bad
   </p>
<div id="p3" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo()"> 
    Pretty
   </p>
<div id="p4" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo()"> 
    Ugly
   </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the value you want to display when you call your javascript function. As you said you are a beginner of Javascript I rearranged like below. hope this helps

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function moreInfo(p){
    var para= document.createElement("p")
    var divObj = document.getElementById("results");
    divObj.innerHTML = ""; // remove the previous clicks results
    divObj.appendChild(para);
    var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is " + p);
    para.appendChild(txt);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="p1" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo('good')"> Good </p>
</div>
<div id="p2" class="divStyle">
  <p onclick="moreInfo('bad')"> Bad</p>
</div>
<div id="p3" class="divStyle">
  <p onclick="moreInfo('pretty')"> Pretty</p>
</div>
<div id="p4" class="divStyle">
  <p onclick="moreInfo('ugly')"> Ugly</p>
</div>
<div id='results'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code ,and tried your requirement.The remaining part is to remove the element created before displaying new element.

Here is the code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function moreInfo(ClickedId){
    var myElem = document.getElementById('extraP');
    if (myElem !== null) {
        myElem.remove();
        }
    var para= document.createElement("p")
    para.setAttribute("id", "extraP");
    if(ClickedId == "p1"){
        var divObj = document.getElementById("p1");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is good");
        divObj.appendChild(para);
    }
    if(ClickedId == "p2"){
        var divObj = document.getElementById("p2");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is bad");
        divObj.appendChild(para);
    }
    if(ClickedId == "p3"){
        var divObj = document.getElementById("p3");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is pretty");
        divObj.appendChild(para);
    }
    if(ClickedId == "p4"){
        var divObj = document.getElementById("p4");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is ugly");
        divObj.appendChild(para);
    }
    para.appendChild(txt);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="p1" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this.parentNode.id)"> 
    Good
   </p>
<div id="p2" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this.parentNode.id)"> 
    Bad
   </p>
<div id="p3" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this.parentNode.id)"> 
    Pretty
   </p>
<div id="p4" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this.parentNode.id)"> 
    Ugly
   </p>
</div>
</html>
```

Please let me know whether it helps you or not.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much. The code worked, but for the first one to work, I just had to remove the RemoveChild part

Comment: I have updated my answer and it is perfectly working

Answer (score 0):

You can summarize your code by changing a little bit.Create a result `p` for display current click description.Use `this` as a param for get current element and `innerHTML` for get inner string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function moreInfo(t){
var para= document.getElementById("result");
para.innerHTML = "";//to set empty for new click
var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is "+t.innerHTML);
para.appendChild(txt);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="p1" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this)"> 
    Good
   </p>
<div id="p2" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this)"> 
    Bad
   </p>
<div id="p3" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this)"> 
    Pretty
   </p>
<div id="p4" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this)"> 
    Ugly
   </p>
</div>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to note:

1. You're reassigning the same variable (var divObj) four times.
2. The same goes for the var txt.
3. Ideally you would assign each once and then create your string dynamically based on which item was clicked.

note: i assigned the function to the 'window' object ( window.moreInfo(string) ) but you could still use ( function moreInfo(string) ) more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window
here is one possible solution (there are many - just hoping this one might be easy to follow):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.moreInfo = function(string){
    var target = event.target;
    var para= document.createElement("p");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is " + string);
    target.appendChild(para).appendChild(txt);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="p1" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo('good')"> 
    Good
   </p>
<div id="p2" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo('bad')"> 
    Bad
   </p>
<div id="p3" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo('pretty')"> 
    Pretty
   </p>
<div id="p4" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo('ugly')"> 
    Ugly
   </p>
</div>
<div id="p4" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo()"> 
    No parameter
   </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked exactly like how I wanted done!! But i tried deleting "No parameter" and it still worked so idk if that was alright to do

Comment: yeah i just added that to show you what might happen if the function doesn't get anything passed in like this:`moreInfo()`

Comment: if this worked for you, feel free to mark as the working solution!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JS code with this:

```
function moreInfo(e){
    var str = e.currentTarget.parentElement.id;
    switch(str) {
        case "p1":
            var obj = document.getElementById("p1");
            var para= document.createElement("p");
            para.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This product is good"))
            obj.appendChild(para);
            break;
        case "p2":
            obj = document.getElementById("p2");
            para= document.createElement("p");
            para.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This product is bad"))
            obj.appendChild(para);
            break;
        case "p3":
            obj = document.getElementById("p3");
            para= document.createElement("p");
            para.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This product is pretty"))
            obj.appendChild(para);
            break;
        case "p4":
            obj = document.getElementById("p4");
            para= document.createElement("p");
            para.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This product is ugly"))
            obj.appendChild(para);
            break;
        default:
            alert("clicked on "+str);
    }
}
```

and Replace your HTML code with below:

```
<div id="p1" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(event)"> Good </p>
</div>
<div id="p2" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(event)"> Bad </p>
</div>
<div id="p3" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(event)"> Pretty </p>
</div>
<div id="p4" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(event)"> Ugly </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code by close div and write javascript to append to specific element you click.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function moreInfo(object){
    var status = object.innerHTML;
    var txt = document.createTextNode("This product is " + status);
    var para= document.createElement("p");
    var divObject = object.parentNode;
    var allP = divObject.childNodes;
    // prevent double add
    if (allP.length > 1) {
        divObject.removeChild(divObject.childNodes[2]);
    }
    divObject.appendChild(para);
    para.appendChild(txt);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="p1" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this)"> 
    Good
   </p>
</div>
<div id="p2" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this)"> 
    Bad
   </p>
</div>
<div id="p3" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this)"> 
    Pretty
   </p>
</div>
<div id="p4" class="divStyle">
    <p onclick="moreInfo(this)"> 
    Ugly
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `html` `div` are not at all balanced.There is no closing `tag` for some of the `div`. As a result it has become nested DOM.

```
var _getClickedElement =document.getElementsByTagName('p');

// Attaching eventlistener to each p tag
for(var i =0; i<_getClickedElement.length;i++){
  var _m = i;  //because of event delegation binding i with the element
  _getClickedElement[_m].addEventListener('click',function(event){
    var _getParentId = this.parentNode.id; // get parent Id of click element
    _showDesc(_getParentId);
})
}


// This function will create p to show the description
function _showDesc(parentId){
var text = "";
switch(parentId) {
    case "p1":
        text ="This product is good";
      break;
     case "p2":
        text ="This product is bad"
        break;
    case "p3":
        text ="This product is pretty"
        break;
    case "p4":
        text ="This product is ugly"
        break;
}

//Remove any previous description tag.

var _getPrevElement =document.getElementById('desc');
if(_getPrevElement !== null){
_getPrevElement.parentNode.removeChild(_getPrevElement);
}


var para= document.createElement("p");
para.id = "desc"
para.innerHTML =text;
document.getElementById(parentId).appendChild(para);
}
```

Click [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/7j81fL9e/) to see live action